# initialize part of a const std::map from another const std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, stdmap

I have a const std::map< int, std::string> initialized like so:

```
const std::map< int, std::string > firstMap = {
    { 1, "First" },
    { 2, "Second"}
};
```

Then I want to make another const std::map which uses the first map as part of its initial values and also has extends the original data. So it would be something similar to this I guess:

```
const std::map< int, std::string > secondMap = {
    { <firstMap>},
    { 3, "Third"}
};
```

so that the secondMap has the three pairs. Is this possible?

EDIT: Also the maps are declared extern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While [@Rakete111's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50238169/434551) is perfectly valid for what you need, I suggest elevating that to a function. Maybe you can use it multiple places.

```
std::map<int, std:::string> combine(std::map<int, std::string> const& map1,
                                    std::map<int, std::string> const& map2)
{
   std::map<int, std:::string> res(map1);
   res.insert(map2.begin(), map2.end());
   return res;
}
```

and then use

```
const auto secondMap = combine(firstMap,
                               std::map<int, std::string>{{3, "Third"}});
```

Comment: It turns out that I am using an extern std::map which is defined differently for a given implementation, and the lambda that  Rakete1111 suggested could not bind to a non auto storage type, so I went with the defined function. Both could be considered correct for my specific question however.

Answer (score 9):

No, `std::map` doesn't have the right constructor for this. What you can do however is use a lambda to initialize the variable in place.

```
const auto secondMap = [&firstMap] {
    std::map<int, std::string> map(firstMap);
    map[3] = "Third";
    return map;
}();
```

Comment: Interesting, do you have any insight on how the a standard compiler would generally handle this compared to a regular const? Should it be computed at run-time or compile time? would constexpr be useful here?

Comment: @Daniel Well you can't make it `constexpr` because `std::map` doesn't support that yet. Yes, initialization will happen at runtime, just like a normal initializer being evaluated.